# app engine datastore auto-clears every time project runs

Tags: django, google-app-engine, djangoappengine

Every time I run my project (eith dev_appserver.py myapp or manage.py runserver in django), the datastore will be cleared. I have persisted the data by model.put() or model.save() in django. In the current session, I can see the data in the admin page, but next time I run the project, all previous datastore is lost.

I know app engine has the --clear_datastore run condition, but i dont't want this feature.

By the way, where is there a local datastore file?

Comment: same here... but not EVERY time. seems like the local_db.bin gets deleted sometimes. Diff is that I am on Java.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest SDK, there were some recent issues fixed I believe..

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `--datastore_path=/datastore/path/dev_appserver.datastore` parameter with dev_appserver.py

`--blobstore_path=/path/to/blobstore/folder` is an option too.

Comment: Note that the default `--datastore_path` is usually in `/tmp` on Linux and Mac, so if your machine is set up to clear out `/tmp` periodically (such as on host startup), that would explain an occasional emptying of the development datastore.  As aschimd00 advises, you can set this path to somewhere else that doesn't get deleted.

Comment: thanks. i just found it's the sdk that causes the problem. no more issue under sdk 1.6.6.

Answer (score 1):

in fact the --datastore_path= is not the best flag to use because it only sets part of the storage options
The best IMHO is:

--storage_path=...

Path at which all local files (such as the Datastore, Blobstore files, Google Cloud Storage Files, logs, etc) will be stored, unless overridden by --datastore_path, --blobstore_path, --logs_path, etc.

found at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver?csw=1

Comment: why the down vote? it's absolutely correct and tested, straight out of the documentation!